# How can I display chrono DateTime without fractional seconds?

Tags: datetime, rust, rfc3339

If I print the current time directly, it includes many trailing decimals:

```
println!("{:?}", chrono::offset::Utc::now());
```

```
2022-12-01T07:56:54.242352517Z
```

How can I get it to print like this?

```
2022-12-01T07:56:54Z
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`to_rfc3339_opts`](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.23/chrono/struct.DateTime.html#method.to_rfc3339_opts). It accepts arguments for the format of the seconds and if the `Z` should be present.

```rust
let time = chrono::offset::Utc::now();
let formatted = time.to_rfc3339_opts(chrono::SecondsFormat::Secs, true);

println!("{:?}", time);    // 2022-12-01T08:32:20.580242150Z
println!("{}", formatted); // 2022-12-01T08:32:20Z
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4a6cf6baa5abf2c72681ea6da2a79ab2)